# Creating a large tooltip glossary on a site, using a shortcode for editors? Is jQuery the right solution?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, tooltip

Working on a bit of a hobby site built on wordpress. Said hobby has a large (few hundred) terms that may appear many times in the page with certain info a user would likely want to call up, and so I have [tooltipster](https://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/)'s plugin implemented to do the display of the tooltips on hover.

However, as the idea is to eventually scale the site so that other non-dev folks could add content; I want a user-friendly way for them to be able to insert the tooltip as they're writing.

Right now the tooltips are just in a paragraph like so:

```
<p>This is my paragraph with a certain <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="#Three_Word_Term">Three Word Term</span> in it. When it's hovered the tooltip displays. </p>
```

Ideally I'd use some kind of easy shortcode so they could write a sentence with a {!Three Word Term}. And that's all they'd have to do on their end.

So I'm trying to think of a way that would basically grab {!Text String} and replace it with the span and class info, plus an ID that matches the text string it picks up ID="Text_String". Specifically I'm trying to avoid defining each term and what it would be replaced with, but have it auto grab the term from between {!*} (or something to that effect) and reuse it within the replacement bit.

I *think* this is something that can be done with a jQuery? I know I can find and replace, I just don't know if I can "find" text between certain markers, and then reuse that in the replace.

Also don't know if jQuery is the best/cleanest solution for this? I'm absolutely a beginner and just teaching myself as I go, so hand holding and input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking... you want the users to enter a text, like:

```
<p id="myP">This is my paragraph with a certain {!Three Word Term} in it. When it's hovered the tooltip displays.</p>
```

and then when it saves, replace the text with

```
<p id="myP">This is my paragraph with a certain <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="#Three_Word_Term">Three Word Term</span> in it. When it's hovered the tooltip displays. </p>
```

I added the id with the assumption that you have some way of grabbing this specific paragraph element (I'll just use the id). You can grab the paragraph's entered text in jQuery with `var enteredText = $("#myP").html();`

If you are trying to match entered patterns and replace them, you may want to learn a little about JavaScript "regular expressions". They are difficult (especially with someone new to JavaScript) but very useful for things like this. Here is a regular expression you could use to find all terms in the given text that have capital letters, lowercase letters, or spaces surrounded by {! and }

`var myRegex = /\{!([A-Z\s]+)\}/gi`;

Yes, it's messy, but figuring this regular expression out is probably the hardest part. Now you can use `.match` to just see if something in this pattern exists in the entered text:

```
var foundText = "";

if( enteredText.match( myRegex ) != null)
  foundText = enteredText.match( myRegex )[0];
```

If the pattern was matched above, now you can use some string methods to work with the found term.

```
var textToReplaceEnteredText = "";

// ... do some stuff with the foundText and enteredText strings above
// ... use those to build the textToReplaceEnteredText string
// ... I'll let you work this out. You may want to use the .replace method of strings

// Finally, use jQuery's .html method again, to replace the paragraph's HTML text
$("#myP").html( textToReplaceEnteredText );
```